# Validation conventions in Java

Tags: java

I have an object. Let's call it `Customer' that is being serialized from a JSON object. Customer has many different fields, but for simplicity let's say that it has twenty (five of which are phone numbers). Is there any sort of convention for validating these fields? I've created one giant method that checks each individual field itself or by calling a method for certain length constraints, email downcasing and validation, phone numbers are stripped of all non-numeric values, length checked, validated, and so on.

All of these methods are held within the Customer class and it's starting to become a little sloppy for my liking. Should I create another class called `CustomerValidators`? Perhaps several other classes such as `EmailValidator`, `PhoneValidator` etc.? Is there any sort of convention here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I think your suggestion about creating `CustomerValidation` and other classes, is very good. And Maybe you can perform validations when a user is inputing those information, i.e. on client side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your customer object use-case specific? I recommend exposing a use-case specific object for service invocations. The data from this object is then mapped onto your reusable, rich domain objects. (Eg using Dozer).

The reason we have use-case specific objects for service in/out payloads is the "don't spill your guts" principle (aka contract first) - this way you can evolve your application model without effecting service subscribers.

Now the validation:

- You can use the annotation-based JSR-303 validation to verify that the input falls within acceptable ranges.
- More complex rules are expressed with methods on the rich domain model. Avoid the anaemic domain classes anti-pattern - let them have rich, OO behaviors. To do this they may need to enlist collaborators. Use dependency injection to provide these. DI on non-container managed classes' eg persistent model instances can be achieved using Spring's @Configurable annotation (among other ways).

Comment: See @GaryF's answer for great info on applying JSR303

Answer (score 2):

Try JSR-303 Bean validation. It lets you do things like:

```
public class Customer {

  @Size(min=3, max=5) //standard annotation
  private String name;

  @PhoneNumber(format="mobile") //Custom validation that you can write
  private String mobile;

  @PhoneNumber(format="US Landline") //... and reuse, with customisation
  private String landline

  @Email //Or you can reuse libraries of annotations that others make, like this one from Hibernate Validator
  private String emailAddress;


  //... ignoring methods

}
```

The best documentation of this, in my opinion, is for the [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) implementation of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course the [Java EE validation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html). How suitable it is for you depends on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a JSON structure filled with data that require validation you might have a look into [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/). Although it is still in draft it is not that complicated to learn.

A simple JSON schema might look like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "id": "http://your-server/path/to/schema#",
    "title": "Name Of The JSON Schema",
    "description": "Simple example of a JSON schema",

    "definitions": {
        "date-time": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "Example of a date-time format like '2013-12-30T16:15:00.000'",
            "properties": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^(2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)[T| ]?([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]{1,3}[Z]?)?$"
            }
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "properties": "{
        "nameOfField": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nameOfSomeIntegerArray": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "minItems": 0,
            "maxItems": 30,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "nameOfADateField": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/date-time"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "nameOfRequiredField1", "nameOfRequiredField2" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

The definitions part allows the definition of some element you can refer to using `"$ref"`. The URI following `"$ref"` starts with a `#` which means it refers to the local schema; `http://your-server/path/to/schema` so to say. In the sample above it defines a date-time format which can be used to validate JSON fields a reference to the date-time definition has been set for. If the value inside the field does not match the regular expression validation will fail.

In Java a couple of libraries are available. I'm currently using [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) from Francis Galiegue. Validating a JSON object using this framework is quite simple:

```
public boolean validateJson(JsonObject json) throws Exception
{
    // Convert the JsonObject (or String) to a internal node
    final JsonNode instance = JsonLoader.fromString(json.toString());
    // Load the JsonSchema
    final JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromResource("fileNameOfYourJsonSchema");

    // Create a validator which uses the latest JSON schema draft
    final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
    final JsonValidator validator = factory.getValidator();

    // Validate the JSON object
    final ProcessingReport report = validator.validate(schema, instance);

    // optional error output
    final Iterator<ProcessingMessage> iterator = report.iterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext() )
    {
        final ProcessingMessage message = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(message.getMessage());
        // more verbose information are available via message.getJson()
    }

    return report.isSuccess();
}
```